# Error SSH to a Centos 7 VM (Host-only)

Tags: ssh, virtualbox, debian, centos, centos-7

I have the following setup:

- Host System: Debian Wheezy
- VirtualBox System: Centos 7
- Network Adapters: NAT and Host-only

On the host system I can "ping" the VM machine,  when I try to ssh I get the following error: Connection Refused

When I change the VM's network adapter to Bridge, I can connect without problem. I would like to have the Host-only connection working because of the fixed IP Address.

--- More Info

**VirtualBox Network Configuration**

*NAT*

Board Type: Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (82540EM)

*Host-only*

Board Type: Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (82540EM)

promiscuous mode: Refuse (tried all of them)

*Bridge*

Board Type: Intel PRO/1000 MT Desktop (82540EM)

promiscuous mode: Refuse

**Comands Ping/SSH**

Ping works but ssh does not.

Instead of 8.8.8.8, I put the real ip addr.

ping 8.8.8.8

ssh leila@8.8.8.8

ssh 8.8.8.8

**Centos**

*ip add* does not list the Host-only IP Address, but it lists the Bridge Address.

Comment: What are the commands you are using to ping and ssh?  What is the network & IP address configuration for both the host-only interface and both interfaces inside the VM?

Comment: I have just added more information.

Comment: Did you followed this? https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html what error are you getting from ssh?

Comment: I'm getting "Connection Refused".  I think it might be the DHCP configuration on Centos. The host-only network has a DHCP server address. I'm trying to figure out how to change the settings.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to connect to the VM that's behind a NAT so, you need to forward ports of the NAT's router (just the same that you would do on a physical one).

On VirtualBox go to:

> **Archive > Preferences > Network > Add new NAT Network > Edit**

Adjust your options for your network and go to

> **Ports forwarding**

Add a new rule looking like this:

> TCP    0.0.0.0    22    192.168.0.10    10005

Now you should be able to connect from your physical machine with:

```
ssh root@<physical machine ip adress> -p 10005
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using NAT, then you'll probably need to forward ports at VirtualBox.
You can look how to do it [here](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#natforward)
It's very similar with routine port forwarding at your home router actually.

Also, you need to be sure that your iptables config allows incoming SSH connections too, you can see how to check for that and enable it [here](https://serversuit.com/community/technical-tips/easy-setup-of-iptables-on-your-new-linux-server.html).

Then you can test connect to your VM with SSH.